# How to get the Slack DM channel ID of the Slack App

Tags: slack-api

I have created a simple Slack App app where the only purpose is to send a message to a channel. I understand that there is the `conversations.list` API to list all public channels to get the correct ID.

However, as a first step, I just want to send the message to the app channel itself. If I use the D... ID it works as expected. No invite by the channel is needed. But how do I get this ID? `conversations.list` only returns publich channels, but no the app channel itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Slack, there is no such thing as an app's channel. There is a DM channel between every user and your app/bot. In these terms, to send a DM message from your app/bot to the user, you need to know `ID` of this user and specify it as a `channel` argument of the `postMessage` API request.

Comment: So every user has DM channel with the app, right?

Comment: Yes, and the user ID can be used as an ID of such channel.

Comment: Now I understood. This makes it clear. Thank you.

Comment: @RuslanIsay on further inspection, this is actually only true for `chat.postMessage` (see ["Begin a conversation in a user's App Home"](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage#app_home)). Other API methods which expect a channel ID won't accept a user ID.

Answer (score 3):

The ability to pass a Slack user ID as `channel` is somewhat unique to `chat.postMessage`. If you try this with other API methods which expect a channel ID only (`conversations.info`), you'll get `"error": "channel_not_found"`. The docs state:

> #### Begin a conversation in a user's App Home
>
> Start a conversation with users in your [App Home](https://api.slack.com/reference/app-home).
>
> With the `chat:write` scope enabled, call `chat.postMessage` and pass a user's ID (`U0G9QF9C6`) as the value of `channel` to post to that user's App Home channel. You can use their direct message channel ID (as found with `im.open`, for instance) instead.
>
> ---
>
> *Source: https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage#app_home*

*Note: The above behavior assumes you're using the bot token. If you provide the user token instead, you'll make the user DM themselves.*

Now, if you *do* need to get a user's *App Home channel ID* for use outside of `chat.postMessage`, keep reading... Here are three ways to do it, each with their own shortcomings:

#### 1. `chat.postMessage`

Well, it's worth mentioning that if you *are* going to use `chat.postMessage`, it returns the resolved channel ID in its response: `"channel": "D01234ABCDE"`. You can save this for later use.

#### 2. `conversations.open`

The API method `im.open` referenced in the docs above has been renamed to `conversations.open`, which can be used to obtain the user's App Home channel ID:

- Use the user token, and set `users` to the app bot ID, or
- Use the bot token, and set `users` to the user ID.

Though, I've observed some weirdness with `conversations.open`, which may or may not be a dealbreaker for you:

1. It requires stronger OAuth permission scopes than ones required to initiate a private DM with a user than `chat.postMessage` (a bot token with `chat:write` is insufficient), and
2. It behaves strangely with respect to the "open state" of a conversation. For example...

   - I tested this method with a user token.
   - The user for that token already had a DM channel with the app! (Doesn't that mean the conversation is already open?)
   - Strangely, the first response had `is_opened: false` (and subsequent responses had `is_opened: true`).

#### 3. `app_home_opened`

The event [`app_home_opened`](https://api.slack.com/events/app_home_opened) fires when the user opens your App Home. If you handle this event, you can save the `channel` in the event payload on your server and use it later, obviating the need to later call `conversations.open`.

Since the event only occurs if and when the user opens your app's App Home,  this approach is more of an optimization than a standalone solution.

#### 4. A better way...?

Due to the drawbacks outlines above, if anyone knows a better way of getting the App Home channel ID for a Slack user, please, comment on this answer!

Comment: I ended up using the chat.postMessage(...) method and caching the bot<>user channel ID for further use.

Answer (score 1):

To mxxk question about 'better way', one different way that may help some folks is to use the method below to find the users ID.

To use postMessage to a user you can also

1. use lookupByEmail [1] to get the users ID, under the 'id' key of the response
2. use postMessage [2] with the user's ID as the channel value.

References
[1] https://api.slack.com/methods/users.lookupByEmail
[2] https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage

Comment: Thanks, but it's sending back the user id, not the DM id. The user id is easy to get from the UI as well: you go to the user's profile, click on the 3 dots, then click on "Copy member ID".

Answer (score 0):

You can get the channel ID of the app channel through the GUI if you:

1. navigate to a message in the channel
2. go to the more actions men
3. select copy link

The channel ID will be the string following `archives/` eg:
`{myorg}.slack.com/archives/{channel_ID}`

Using this approach would work for any channel in the slack app, though it's unlikely to be the best approach since it's manual vs something more programmatic.