# Get recipient of a DM message in Slack

Tags: slack, slack-api

I have a Slack App that listens to `message` events with the appropriate user and bot scopes (The app has `im:read` and `im:history` permissions among others, on behalf of the user). The event payload looks like this:

```json
{"client_msg_id": "...", 
"type": "message", 
"text": "...", 
"user": "<sender id>", 
"ts": "...", 
"team": "...", 
"blocks": [...], 
"channel": "D012345678 <example direct channel id>", 
"event_ts": "...", 
"channel_type": "im"}
```

Is there a way to identify the recipient id of this message?

1. I have looked into `conversations_members` API and used the channel_id provided by the event payload. It throws a `channel_not_found` error.  I tried a hardcoded test with an actual private channel that the user of the app is in, and it returned the list of user-ids as expected. So it seems like the issue is related to DM channels.
2. Tried to use the user-id instead of the channel id [as this comment suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65648612/how-to-get-the-slack-dm-channel-id-of-the-slack-app#comment116154645_65695843). Didn't work either.

Any help is appreciated.

**Additional info:**

`pip freeze | grep slack`

```
slack-bolt==1.13.2
slack-sdk==3.16.1
```

Comment: Did you ever find out the answer to this?

Comment: Yes. Will post it as a separate answer. Thanks for reminding me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who is facing the same issue, I asked the SlackBolt devs to pitch in and [here's their answer.](https://github.com/slackapi/python-slack-sdk/issues/1216) . In summary, `conversation_members` mentioned in the questuon is the correct starting point. But if both your user and bot tokens have `im:read` permissions, the priority is to the bot token. Replace it with user token and you should be fine. More elaborate answer is in the discussion link.